# How can I make this embed into a page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, queue, embed

I created this queue embed for my music bot using discord.js and it work fine, however I'm wondering how to make this embed into page. Thanks in advance!

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
    
    module.exports = {
        name: "queue",
        aliases: ['q'],
        description: "Check the current queue!",
        run: async (client, message, args) => {
            const queue = client.distube.getQueue(message)
            if (!queue) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**Queue for ${message.guild}**`)
            .setDescription(`__Now Playing:__\nNothing Playing!`)
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            );
            
            let string = "";
    
            if(queue.songs[0]) string += `__Now Playing:__\n [${queue.songs[0].name}](${queue.songs[0].url})\n \`${queue.songs[0].formattedDuration} Requested by: ${queue.songs[0].user.tag}\``
            if(queue.songs[1]) string += `\n__Up Next:__\n ${queue.songs.map((song, id) => `\`${id}.\` [${song.name}](${song.url})\n \`${song.formattedDuration} Requested by: ${song.user.tag}\``).slice(1, 10).join("\n")}`
            
            const pages = []
    
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`**Queue for ${message.guild}**`)
            .setDescription(string)
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .addField("\u200B", `**${queue.songs.length} songs in queue | ${queue.formattedDuration} total length**`)
            message.channel.send(embed)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "how to make this embed into page"?

Comment: As @JorgeMontejo said, please clarify what you want to achieve

Comment: basically I'm trying to make this embed into an array and display them as a page where you can use reaction to reach next page of the embed.